# Codeigniter display relational data directly in view from model

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

How can I display data from model **mdl_request** inside view using ajax

this is my model:

```
function get_unit_measurement_by_id($id){
     $this->db->from('items', 'item_unit');
     $this->db->join('item_unit', 'item_unit.item_unit_id = items.item_unit_id');
     $this->db->where('item_unit', $id);
     $query = $this->db->get();
     return $query->row();
}
```

this is my view:

```
<?php
     foreach($requests as $request):
         echo  $this->mdl_request->get_unit_measurement_by_id($request->item_unit);
     endforeach; 
?>
```

Comment: i need to convert the code in view to ajax not via controller url just directly from model, please i need help

Comment: whats your argument trying to desperately avoid the controller here ? you should simply create a function in one of your controllers and call that via ajax

Comment: You can post your modal and controller code.

Comment: That's not a wise way to call the modal directly. You are violating the structure of MVC.

Comment: This is just a bad idea, and one that won't work. You need to load CodeIgniter to use its database and output for views, yet you want to side-step the controller? Stop now and read the CodeIgniter documentation. This is the easiest PHP framework to use, so learn how to use it.

Comment: read: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html and https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html

Comment: But why?? (insert Ryan Reynold meme here)

Answer (score 0):

You can't....In order to display your data straight from that function it needs to be in a controller.